# calculating new column based on previous rows values in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that contains 3 columns (index, Value, Running total of value). I want to create or populate column/measure  (let say called Replaced Value) in such a way that it checks whether Running Total value exceeds a certain threshold (let say 150), then it checks 48 past values of the column named 'Value' and sees if the value is greater than 10 then put 10 in new column otherwise copy the same value of 'Value' column into Replaced Value column. Here is how the structure of the table looks like:

[image]

Could anyone guide me how can we do in power BI

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest, I am quiet new in power BI, I just created DateTime column as shown in the picture. Since then I am stuck, reading different literature online but no luck yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You could have used Rolling sum but since you don't have date reference you will need to follow solution provided in https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Need-help-SUM-or-AVERAGE-last-7-Previous-Records-Not-Using-Date/td-p/505276

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: But how could I test whether value is more or less than certain value and then check previous 48 values.